# Why is my SVG using center-origin coordinates?

Tags: svg, vector

Why are my circles not starting in the upper left corner? What am I missing here?

I'm not sure why 0 of the X axis is in the center of the drawing.

Am I going crazy? :)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="20" viewBox="0 0 100 20">
 <svg x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
 </svg>
 <svg x="20" y="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
 </svg>
 <svg x="40" y="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
 </svg>
 <svg x="60" y="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
 </svg>
 <svg x="80" y="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
 </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: The aspect ratio of the viewBox and the width/height don't match so something's got to give.

Comment: Why are multiple `svg` elements used, and nested inside another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `viewBox="0 0 100 20"` This means that the width in user units is 100 and the height is 20. Meanwhile you are using `width="150" height="20"` 
You may delete the height attribute. In this case the height will be calculated so that the rapport w/h stays the same.
If you need `width="150" height="20"` you may try using a different `viewBox="0 0 150 20"`.

Read more about the [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute

```css
svg{background:#d9d9d9}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150"  viewBox="0 0 100 20">
 <svg x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
 </svg>
 <svg x="20" y="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
 </svg>
 <svg x="40" y="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
 </svg>
 <svg x="60" y="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
 </svg>
 <svg x="80" y="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
 </svg>
</svg>
```